# Как получить значение из JSON в каждый блок с одним классом?

Tags: jquery, json

Есть блок `.example`, всего их 9. Как в каждый блок вынести значение `name` из JSON.

Застопорился на том что в каждый блок с классом `.example` выводит все значения из массива.

```
<div class="exmp__block">
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
    <div class="example"></div>
</div>


$.getJSON('data/directories.json', function(data){
    //console.log(data);
    var i = 0;
    var name = data.response.directories;
    //var blockArr = document.querySelectorAll('.main_block');
    for( i = 0; i <= name.length; i++) {
        console.log(name.length);

        $('.main_block').append(name[i].name);
        console.log(name[i].name);
    };
});

{
    "response": {
        "directories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "значение1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "значение2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "значение3"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "значение4"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "значение5"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "значение6"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "значение7"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "значение8"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "значение9"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Было 2 ошибки одна в условии `i <= name.length;`
вторая в выводе

```
$('.main_block').append(name[i].name);
   console.log(name[i].name);
```

Если есть ошибки пишите

```
$.getJSON('data/directories.json', function(data){
  var name = data.response.directories;
  var blockArr = document.querySelectorAll('.main_block');
  for(var i = 0; i < Math.min(name.length, blockArr.length); i++) {
    $(blockArr[i]).html(name[i].name);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

я это вот так делаю обычно

т.е всё как у вас только в цикле прохожу по блокам и потом вывожу name

а функцию init регистрирую в ready

```js
function init() {
  $.getJSON("main.json", out);
}

function out(data) {
  var out = '';
  for (var key in data) {
    out += '<div class="card">'
    out += '<h2>' + data[key].name + '<h2>'
    out += '</div>'

  }
  $(".biling").html(out)
}

$(function() {
  init();
})
```

пример json

```js
{
  "main": {
    "name": "name",
    "family": "family",
    "stage": "40",
    "country": "counter",
    "city": "city",
    "experience": "4",
    "img": "img/user.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал по вашему примеру, не получается вывести в блок но задумку понял. Добавил переменную var road = data.response.directories[1].name; но в результате выдает undefined. Если можно добавьте пример JSON. Просто пока до меня не дошло, по какому пути он обращается в JSON в переменной out

Comment: @Дмитрий out  это промежуточная переменная

Comment: @Дмитрий я просто показал как я вывел всего одно поле из json а на само деле я json применяю как базу данных

Comment: Хорошо, но вопрос все таки звучал как вывести в каждый блок, значение name из JSON. По вашему примеру тоже можно делать и я тоже считаю что для не больших проектов json можно использовать как базу данных

Comment: так не получилось что ли ?

Comment: нет, так не пошло. С обращением к json  проблема

Comment: mans.deity@mail.ru - лан здесь долго ..пиши на почту